# How to retrieve multiple images from MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to retrieve single image from mysql database using php.

Now I want to retrieve multiple images.

Here is the piece of code:

```
<?php
 --db connection code--
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM try WHERE status='0'";
 $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
 while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
   // set the header for the image
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
   echo mysql_result($result, 0);
   echo '<br>';
 }
?>
```

executing this code, only first image in table is being displayed.
How to retrieve multiple images?

Comment: Db structure ? Db data ?

Comment: You can't show multiple files within one PHP file with `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`

Comment: first image is displayed because of `mysql_result($result, 0);`

Comment: When you request an url form a web server you normally request only **one** file, because your header is just `Content-type: image/jpeg` the result is also just one file. While multipart responses exist, i currently don't know how well supported they are.

Comment: "image" is a filename ?

Comment: You construct $row and then revert to $result. Shurely shome mishtake.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Content-type: image/jpeg`, which means it can only return one image, as the browser will only expect one. If you want to return multiple images to download you have to do some workaround.

One option would be to first pack the files together into one file (like a ZIP archive), and push that to the user.

Or if you don't want to push this as a download, then create a HTML page, with image links to your images. Each of the link will only return one of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the loop counter in `result_mysql`

```
$count=0;
 while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
   // set the header for the image
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
   echo mysql_result($result,$count);

   $count++;
 }
```

Please don't use the error suppressor `@`

[mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

> NOTE : Please don't use mysql* functions in your new code they are
>   depriciated in newer versions use mysqli* or PDO

Comment: mysql() is deprecated

Comment: `echo <br>;` and `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` are you kidding?

Comment: @t.niese i tried to point `mysql_result($result, 0);` mistake there are also others

Comment: @dianuj sure, but if you post an answer what should be changed and copying the invalid code as is and just fixing one part, it would be misleading also for others reading this answer. I think it is better to leave the whole invalid code block out an just state what needs to be changed. Or show a correct code block.

Answer (score 0):

As the *Content-type: image/jpeg* returns only a single image, you should consider saving the paths of the images in your database table. Later on you won't have any problems fetching all of them and echoing the source elements in your html.